# Hide rows based on Drop Down list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

This is basically a mail template, containing 3 different types of content.
I have an excel sheet with a combo-box list.
The list has values 1,2 and 3. & 3 different types of content for them.
When any one of them is selected . The remaining content must be hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have validation option set in `Range("A1")` with different options (1-3 in my example). In the appropriate Sheet module put the following code and change it as needed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
Dim rngOpt1 As Range
Dim rngOpt2 As Range
Dim rngOpt3 As Range
'you doesn't need to put rows references here
'as we deal with it later
    Set rngOpt1 = Range("b10:c15")   'first area to be hidden
    Set rngOpt2 = Range("d16:e20")   'second...
    Set rngOpt3 = Range("f21:g25")   'you can guess
If Range("A1") = 1 Then 'your validation cell
    rngOpt1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    rngOpt2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    rngOpt2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("A1") = 2 Then
    rngOpt1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    rngOpt2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    rngOpt2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    'you can do it on you own... :)
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Each time you change value in A1 the appropriate rows range would be hidden.
I'm not specially proud of its efficiency but it was my first idea.

Comment: thanku for prompt response and excuse for delay but can you please guide me how can i add this and where can i add it. Please bear with me I have not done it before

Comment: start Excel >> Alt+F11 >> project explorer on the left >> find your workbook name >> next to it find your sheet name & double+click on it >> place the my code in opened window

Comment: Yes its working ...And for If Range("A1") = 1 Then ,...how must I use a sentence instead.?I tried "" but

Comment: this `if` statement is case sensitive therefore do the following: `If UCase(Range("A1")) = "HERE YOUR SENTENCE IN UPPER CASES" Then`